# Is it possible to draw primitives in OpenCL?

Tags: opengl, opencl

I'm trying to use a parallel kernel algorithm, but it needs to call OpenGL functions [like draw a line] directly from the kernel, is this possible?
Drawing to a texture object. thx for clues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really.

First of all, OpenGL drawing commands are issued on CPU side (glDrawArrays for instance). In OpenCL kernels you are operating on the GPU and cannot call these methods.

Additionally, in OpenCL you don't even have access to the fixed-function parts of the GPU rendering pipeline like the tessellation unit or rasterizer.

What you can do of course is create a 2D buffer in OpenCL, implement line rendering by yourself and paint "pixels" in there, but that's probably not what you want.

There are also extensions for OpenGL-OpenCL interoperability, a tutorial is here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-and-opengl-interoperability-tutorial

Maybe if you tell us what you want to achieve we can give you better alternatives :)

Comment: I'm building a drawing application and need to run renderings of simple primitives in a massive parallel manner. On CPU->OpenGL I get only few threads, so the idea was to move the rendering to the GPU completely. Wanted to avoid making low level algorithms for rendering primitive let's say "assembler style" since the OpenGL has capability to draw stuff.

Comment: That doesn't sound like OpenCL is the right way... GPUs are generally capable of rendering millions of primitives in a few milliseconds, and that is what OpenGL is made for. Just don't do one draw call per primitive, but put everything you have into a buffer and render that entire buffer at once. That is pretty common and most modern OpenGL tutorials should render stuff in a way that scales to larger number of primitives.

Comment: My problem is I have many scenes,lets say 500. Each scene has peimitives,about 1000. Not sure if creating 500 rendering buffers is the way to go.

Comment: if you have only one scene visible at a time, then you don't need to create them all upfront, but just the one that's visible. if you actually mean objects and they're all on screen, then 500 sounds reasonable. up to maybe 2k draw calls shouldn't bee a big problem. but of course, the less draw calls the better, so you can try batching techniques, but those i don't know very well.

Comment: Actually I don't need to display any of them, just draw primitives and then do OpenCL calculation on each of the scenes. OpenCL part of the problem is easy. Coupling it with the draw part makes my head scratch ;)

Comment: with only piecewise information of what you're trying to do, it's really hard to guess what could be of help to you. also, it's unclear what "scenes" and "primitives" are for you.

Comment: I try again stepwise:
1. Render 1000+ lines to framebuffer/texture
2. Call OpenCL to compute on the buffer
3. Repet the steps in the most parallel way possible

Comment: you might want to look into compute shaders. if you already have a opengl app, they are much easier to use, since they have an easier API and are written in GLSL and you can simply work on your existing textures without requiring any interop stuff.

Comment: Actually I ended up with a solution 
1. render primitives to texture
2. display texture in framebuffer
3. use a shader to do calculations - this could not manage to get working yet.

So thanks, you were right, OpenCL cannot draw, and was a bad idea to want to use it for this.